# Any limitation of variable length in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, robotframework, jmeter-3.2

i am using robotframework with jemetr to automate my API.I am trying to pass the below json data from robotframework script to jmeter but it is  getting failed and if i reduce the json data size it is working fine.Please let me know whether there is any limitation and if yes what is the workaround.

**JSON data:**

```
{"fordate(dd-mm-yyyy)":"21-04-2021","user_id":"1","outlet_id":"10","warehouse_id":"1","skunit_id":"1","Quantity(case)":"","Quantity(units)":"2","Auto Scheme Apply":"","unitprice":"23","po_number":"","po_deliveryTime(dd-mm-yyyy)":"2021-04-22","id":"jqg1"}
```

**Robot keyword:**

```
Run Jmeter      ${jmeter}    ${jmxPath}  ${logPath}   -Jmdmpath=${mdmpath} -Jtestname=${TEST_NAME} -Jmdmid=75 -Jjsondata=${json}
```

Json data is passed via variable `${json}`

Error:

```
10:37:27.702    FAIL    JMeterLibException: 'Value returned by JMeter: 1'   
10:37:27.702    DEBUG   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sadha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 41, in runJmeter
    JMeterRunner(jmeterPath, testPlanPath, logFilePath, otherParams)
  File "/home/sadha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 200, in __init__
    jmeterOutput = self.runAndPrintResult()
  File "/home/sadha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 234, in runAndPrintResult
    raise JMeterLibException("%s %s" % (msg, retValue))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `${json}` in quotation marks like:

```
-Jjsondata='${json}'
```

or make sure to escape **all the special characters** with a backslash `\` in your JSON

---

A better idea would be passing the path to the JSON file and reading the file in JMeter script using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString). If you have multiple files in a folder it makes sense to use [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/)

More information:  [Bash: Special Characters and Quoting](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-the-bash/1565923472/ch01s09.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is space in post data which was cauing the issue